# paramiko ssh client failing in host key signature mismatch

Tags: python, hash, ssh, biginteger, paramiko

We have a SSH server implementation which we are using Paramiko client to test against which consistently fails in host key signature mismatch for diffie-hellman-group-exchange-shaX. I have figured out the reason for the signature mismatch but cannot understand which side server or the client is doing the wrong thing. Below are the reasons for the mismatch

1.Client sends "min || n || max" to Server.

2.Server finds a group that best matches the client's request, and sends
       "p || g" to Client. where p is big prime and g is generator
Now the problem happens where the server sends the generator of size more than one which is represented in byte array with preceding zeros plus with it's length preceding it as(big num representation)

`00 00 00 04 00 00 00 02`  where `04` is the generator length and `02` is it's value. H which is used for host key signature matching uses complete byte buffer for big nums for hashing.  H is represented by

`H = hash(V_C
       || V_S || I_C || I_S || K_S || min || n || max || p || g || e ||
       f || K)`

Now when paramiko stores the generator it removes the preceding zeros and does not store the length.
It converts g back to bytes and pre-pends the byte deflated g's length using len(g) for hashing
using the below routine.

```
def add_string(self, s):
    """                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    Add a string to the stream.                                                                                                                                                                                                          

    :param str s: string to add                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    """
    s = asbytes(s)
    self.add_size(len(s))
    self.packet.write(s)
```

This comes out to be just one byte so what we are essentially hashing for g byte buffer is as follows
`00 00 00 01 02` where 01 is the string length and 02 is the value which is different form server g buffer hence the signature mismatch

So my question here is which side is representing the byte buffer of big nums incorrectly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to RFC4251:

> Blockquote

```
  mpint
  Represents multiple precision integers in two's complement format,
  stored as a string, 8 bits per byte, MSB first.  Negative numbers
  have the value 1 as the most significant bit of the first byte of
  the data partition.  If the most significant bit would be set for
  a positive number, the number MUST be preceded by a zero byte.
  Unnecessary leading bytes with the value 0 or 255 MUST NOT be
  included.  The value zero MUST be stored as a string with zero
  bytes of data.
  eg: 80(hex)                 00 00 00 02 00 80
```

Hence what the server is doing is wrong and paramiko is right in removing the preceding padded zeros.